# Are there "2-Lawvere theories" with 2-categories and 2-functors and models in $\mathbf{Cat}$?

Tags: reference-request, higher-category-theory, lawvere-theory

Let $\mathbf{FinDiscCat}$ be the 2-category of all discrete categories with finitely many objects as 0-cells, all functors as 1-cells and all natural transformations as 2-cells. Does $\mathbf{FinDiscCat}$ have all finite coproducts in the same way $\mathbf{FinSet}$ of Lawvere theories has all finite coproducts? Does it have an opposite category $\mathbf{FinDiscCat^{op}}$ where those coproducts become products? Does the concepts "coproduct", "product" and "opposite category" even make sense for 2-categories? Does $\mathbf{FinDiscCat^{op}}$ have  a skeleton $\mathbf{F^2}$? Otherwise, just assume the regular $\mathbf{F}$, skeleton of $\mathbf{FinSet^{op}}$, wherever $\mathbf{F^2}$ is written, and functors instead of 2-functors.

Has anyone investigated the concept of a "2-Lawvere theory" as a product-preserving 2-functor $\operatorname{I^2_{L^2}}$ form $\mathbf{F^2}$ to a 2-category $\mathbf{L^2}$ of categories

$$\mathbf{C_0}, \mathbf{C_1}, \mathbf{C_2}, … \in \mathbf{L^2},$$

one for each non-negative whole number $n$, and models as 2-functors ${\operatorname{M^2}}$ from $\mathbf{L^2}$ to $\mathbf{Cat}$?

Of course, similar concepts are also of interest.